# fetching values in three dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a PHP array, where in the pipe dai, class and the thickness,Pressure, OD, Id are incorporated in three dimensional manner.

Now I want to match the Pipe size, class then pick the pressure and thickness

```
<?php
// Pipe Size, class, OD, ID, Thickness, Pressure.
$data = array(
   “size 100”=>array(“K7” => array(112, 95, 4.5, 12.0),
            (“K8” => array(112, 95, 3.5, 11.0),
                    (“K9” => array(112, 95, 2.5, 11.0)),

   “size 150”=>array(“K7” => array(163, 145, 4.6, 10.0),
            (“K8” => array(163, 145, 3.8, 13.0),
                    (“K9” => array(163, 145, 2.9, 15.0)),

   “size 200”=>array(“K7” => array(210, 195, 5.5, 10.0),
            (“K8” => array(210, 195, 4.1, 13.0),
                    (“K9” => array(210, 195, 3.5, 15.0))

);
```

I want the pressure and thickness, when certain size & class is submitted by the html form. The results to be posted in following manner:

```
When the thickness is above: ($ans1) mm, 
the Pressure would be: arraived: ($ans2) Mpa
```

the HTML Form is

```
<form method="post" name="data" action="data.php">

PIPE SIZE :  
  <select name="size" style="width: 100px"   >
  <option value="100">100 mmm 
  <option value="150"> 150 mm
  <option value="200">200 mm 
  </select>
<br><br>
 CLASS: 
<select name="class" style="width: 100px"  >
  <option value="K7"> K7
  <option value="K8"> K8
  <option value="K9"> K9
</select>
<br><br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="SUBMIT">&nbsp;
<input type="Reset"  name="reset" value ="RESET" onClick ="(form);" />
 </form>
```

Comment: provide your html form if you need help with that as well. You may do that by clicking "edit" on your original question

Comment: Mr. Code Godie, the HTML form is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

Assuming you have an array like this (your array needs some editing)

```
$data = array(
    "100" => array(
        "K7" => array(112, 95, 4.5, 12.0),
        "K8" => array(112, 95, 3.5, 11.0),
        "K9" => array(112, 95, 2.5, 11.0)
        ),
    "150" => array(
        "K7" => array(163, 145, 4.6, 10.0),
        "K8" => array(163, 145, 3.8, 13.0),
        "K9" => array(163, 145, 2.9, 15.0)
        ),
    "200" => array(
        "K7" => array(210, 195, 5.5, 10.0),
        "K8" => array(210, 195, 4.1, 13.0),
        "K9" => array(210, 195, 3.5, 15.0)
        )
);
```

Then look for those classes and sizes like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $thickness = $data[$size][$class][2];
    $pressure = $data[$size][$class][3];

    echo "When the thickness is above: ($thickness) mm<br>";
    echo "the Pressure would be: arraived: ($pressure) Mpa";
}
```

Also change your `submit input` FROM this: `<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="SUBMIT"` TO this `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

Comment: thanks for the HTML i will update my answer now that I understand what your goal is

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php 
$size_param = $_POST("size"); // like "size 100"
$class_param = $_POST("class"); // like "K7"

$pressure = $data[$size_param][$class_param][3];
$thickness = $data[$size_param][$class_param][2];

echo "When the thickness is above: ($size_param) mm,<br>the Pressure would be: arraived: ($pressure) Mpa";
?>
```

Comment: I edited my answer... that is supposing your html form contains "size" input and a "class" input